# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{89} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ)+1}=44.5$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, summation

So I've been stuck on this problem for a while now, and to be honest I have no idea how to start. I stumbled upon it while practicing for an Olympiad, and it is a past Olympiad problem (for teens) itself.

The problem is as follows:

Given is the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^3+1}$

Prove that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{89} f(\tan(k^\circ)) = 44.5$$

In other words, prove that:

$$\frac{1}{\tan^3(1^\circ)+1} + \frac{1}{\tan^3(2^\circ)+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\tan^3(89^\circ)+1} = 44.5 $$

The question was multiple choice at first, but I managed to figure out 44.5 with my calculator. I still wondered how one would come up with a proof.
Any guidelines or straight up solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write [$\tan(90^\circ - k^\circ) = \frac{1}{\tan(k^\circ)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952169/is-cot-x-tan-%CF%80-2-x-true-for-any-angle-x).
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{89} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} &= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \sum_{k=46}^{89} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \frac{1}{\tan^3(45^\circ) + 1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{1}{\tan^3(90 - k^\circ) + 1} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ)} + 1} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{\tan^3(k^\circ)}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \frac{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1}{\tan^3(k^\circ) + 1} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= 44.5
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense now that I see your solution. I would have never thought of complementary angles otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Use $f(x)+f(1/x)=1$, $\tan(90^\circ-x)=1/\tan x$, and $\sum_{k=1}^{89}a_k=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{89}(a_k+a_{90-k})$ with $a_k:=f(\tan k^\circ)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the use of complementary angles! I forgot those existed!